# how to visualize/plot SOM in python?

Tags: python, visualization, som, self-organizing-maps

I want to create a map for my cluster result [(this kind of map)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIL1a.png).For example, this is the result that I generate using SOM.

Example of my input (based on DNA sequence motif):

motif 1 = 0.19,0.95,0.01,0,0.76,0,1.04,0,0,0.05,0,1,0,0,1,0

motif 2 =0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.3,0.05,0.15,0.7,0.6,0.05,1.15,0.2,0.8

motif 3 =0.9,0,0,1.1,0,0,0,0.45,0.035,0,0.015,0.15,1.665,0,0.335,1.35

motif 4 =1,0,0,1.16,0.036,0,0.0032,0.4,0.294,0,0.025,0.04,1.5888,0.04,0.371,1.04

Output (run using SOM in python):
Cluster for training input:
motif 1 = Cluster 1

motif 2 = Cluster 2

motif 3 = Cluster 1

motif 4 = Cluster 1

weight for node 1:
1.366,0.951,0.819,0.919,0.812,0.688,0.802,0.622,0.999,0.574,0.618,0.803,0.880,0.721,0.741,0.963
weight for node 2:
1.366,0.951,0.819,0.919,0.812,0.688,0.802,0.622,0.999,0.574,0.618,0.803,0.880,0.721,0.741,0.963

Comment: Are you using only two nodes? How about plotting a scatter-plot or `plt.imshow` where each node represents one point on a 2D grid and the color corresponds to the major class in that node? In the SUSI, package, this is called `estimation_map`, maybe this helps: https://github.com/felixriese/susi/blob/master/examples/SOMClassifier_Salinas.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same, but came across a good alternative. It's called a starburst plot and is in a SOM implementation called popsom, developed and maintained by Dr. Lutz Hamel and his former students.

**[Example of the graphical representation:](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/njali2001/popsom/master/image/animal_1.png)**

[popsom for python](https://github.com/njali2001/popsom)

[popsom for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/popsom/index.html)